# Firefox keeps forgetting my proxy settings. Help!

Tags: firefox, proxy

I'm pretty sure that *normally* Firefox remembers any changes you make in Tools -> Options -> Network -> Settings.

However these days it completely forgets them whenever I restart, and instead I get an HTTP proxy of 127.0.1.1 and a Port of 8888.

Why is it doing this and can I fix it?

Comment: what operating system are you using? Did you configure the proxy at the OS level or in firefox?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should not happen

1. Disable all plugins.
2. Check for a virus. Maybe you got infected and the virus redirects all traffic so it can examine it for logins and password.

Answer (score 0):

In my case disabling Fiddler add-on corrected this problem.